# Does Java have any known issues with Images and displaying them

Tags: java, swing, icons, photos, graphic

I am new to Java but not new to graphics
I'm trying to expand my understanding with a project in which I'm displaying many photos of items using JLabels and Icons to display them,

The items pictures are garnished from various locations on the net and so many sources.

I've converted these into PNG files as they have transparent backgrounds to them.

Thing is I wasted a whole weekend recently checking and re-checking some code because one item just would not display, following the logic to its conclusion told me it was the file that was at fault, even though the file displayed correctly in photoshop?

I went into the file to see what was unique about it, but apart from being 8 bit instead of 32 bit there was no difference I could find.

...and so to my question, does Java have problems with displaying any particular types of file formats that perhaps I should know prior to actually finding out the hard way.

Sorry for no code as the question does not warrant it.

I think the file that caused me problems was pulled from here
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d5/XXXX_Logo.png

Comment: Java should be able to handle png just fine. You have to use outside libraries to show vector formats such as SVG.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand it, Java should be able to handle PNG just fine. There *are* some formats that Java doesn't support including vector image formats such as SVG. But for most of these, there are outside libraries that can help.

With regards to the image example that you've linked to, [image: XXXX Image], I have no problem getting Java to read and display it:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Foo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String spec = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "en/d/d5/XXXX_Logo.png";
      URL url;
      try {
         url = new URL(spec);
         BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }     
}
```

Regarding your statement,

> Sorry for no code as the question does not warrant it.

I beg to differ. I think that showing code and a reference to the offending image that causes your problem is key towards solving it, and for example if my answer doesn't help you, I strongly urge you to show us just what isn't working in a way that we can reproduce, similar to the code I've posted above.

Comment: I can send you the offending image if I can work out how, I didn't see any attachment option